# How to set onItemselectlistener on Listview?

Tags: android

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical">
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button 
        android:text="AddCar" 
        android:id="@+id/btnaddcar" 
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </Button>   
</LinearLayout>
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:layout_weight="2"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
 </LinearLayout>


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.carlist, null));
 //     setContentView(R.layout.carlist);
    db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    db.open();
    //listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    cararr=new String[db.getCountCar()];
    carimg=new String[db.getCountCar()];
    carimg=db.getImageList();
    cararr=db.getAllCarName();



    /*adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, db.getImageList(),db.getAllCarName());

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);*/

    cararr=db.getAllCarName();
     SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                groupData,
                R.layout.custom_row_view,
                new String[] {"carname","image"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.image}
                );
     populateList();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    //listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
//  listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    db.close();
    btnaddcar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaddcar);
    btnaddcar.setOnClickListener(this);
}
private void populateList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Map<String, String> group;
    db.open();
    cararr=new String[db.getCountCar()];
    carimg=new String[db.getCountCar()];
    carimg=db.getImageList();
    cararr=db.getAllCarName();
    for(int i=0;i<db.getCountCar();i++)
    {
        group = new HashMap<String, String>();
        group.put("carname", cararr[i]);
        group.put("image",carimg[i]);
        groupData.add(group);
    }
    db.close();
}
```

How to set onItemselectlistener on Listview?

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code List OnItemClickListener.

My code is:

```
 String strarray[]=new String[100];
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterarray=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Classname.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,strarray);
 lv.setAdapter(adapterarray);
 lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 

 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str=lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List is:"+str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.i(TAG,str);

    }
});
```

Hope this will help!!